# For which primes $p$ in $\mathbb Z$ is $p\omega$ the sum of two cubes in $\mathbb Q(\omega)$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, diophantine-equations

This is related to an earlier question I posed —"Possible extensions of a conjecture …". Now that my note [arXiv:2309.00162](https://arxiv.org/abs/2309.00162) has appeared I'll use it as a reference.

Elementary results(along with experimental results and non-results)

$1$, $u$, and $v$ are the complex cube roots of $1$. $\mathcal O$ and $\mathcal K$ are $\mathbb Z[u]$ and $\mathbb Q(u)$, and $p$ in $\mathbb Z$ is prime. When $p$ isn't $1$ or $8$ mod $9$, $pu$ isn't a sum of two cubes in $\mathcal K$. For proofs see the arXiv note cited above—Theorem 1.3 when $p$ is $2$ or $5$ mod $9$, Theorem 1.7 when $p$ is $3$, and Theorem 2.2 and the accompanying remark when $p$ is $4$ or $7$ mod $9$. But what happens when $p$ is $1$ or $8$ mod $9$ remains mysterious.

It's not hard to construct many $M$ in $\mathbb Z$, with all the $p$ in $\mathbb Z$ that divide $M$ congruent to $1$ or $8$ mod $9$, such that $Mu$ is a sum of two cubes in $\mathcal K$. I've so far found sixteen such prime $M$. (The ones $< 1000000$ I've found are $487$, $4591$, $17929$, $53731$, $318601$, $601507$, and $628939$). But each of the sixteen is $1$ mod $9$. And in addition to not having yet found any $p$ congruent to $8$ mod $9$ for which $pu$ is such a sum, I lack the ability to show that when $p$ is any prime that's $1$ or $8$ mod $9$, then $pu$ isn't such a sum.

Requests and Questions

(1)...Produce $p$ that are $8$ mod $9$ such that $pu$ is a two cube sum in $\mathcal K$.

My attempts used the fact that for any such $p$ the equation $ur^3 + vs^3 + put^3 = 0$ has a solution with $r$, $s$, and $t$ non-zero elements of $\mathcal O$ and $r$ and $s$ prime to $p$; this follows from Theorem 1.2 of the arXiv note. Though my attempts failed, I think this is the right track to take in finding such $p$.

(2)....Give proofs that for various $p$ that are $1$ or $8$ mod $9$, $pu$ is not a two cube sum in $\mathcal K$. In particular what are the smallest $p$ that are $1$ mod $9$ (or that are $8$ mod $9$) for which $pu$ is a two cube sum in $\mathcal K$?

I imagine 2-descent is the right approach to take, but since one is working over $\mathcal K$ rather than $\mathbb Q$, this looks messy.

(3).... Mark Watkins in [arXiv:math/0412427](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0412427) has made extensive calculations involving the L-functions attached to the elliptic curves
$x^3 + y^3 = p$ when $p$ is $1$ mod $9$. Assuming that the BSD conjecture holds, they suggest the following. Let $A(n)$ be the number of primes congruent to $1$ mod $9$ and $< n$ that are two cube sums in Q. Then as $n\to\infty$, $\frac{\log(A(n))}{\log(n)}\to\frac{5}{6}$. (For a more precise conjecture see Question 1.4.1 of his article). Can one make similar calculations for the $L$-functions attached to the curves $x^3 + y^3 = pu$, when $p$ is $1$ or $8$ mod $9$?
And do they suggest that Watkins' suspicions have like analogs here?

Comment: @L. Spice  The link to my arXiv article doesn't work--could you please fix that? Thanks

Comment: The title of this question has an $\omega$ in it, the body doesn't. Could you please edit for consistency?

Comment: The discrepancy is intentional, Gerry. Since omega is a common symbol for a particular complex cube root of 1, I think its appearance in the title won't be confusing, and is preferable there to the more meaningless u that I use in the arXiv note. And since I make several references to the arXiv note, I prefer using the u and v of the note in the body of the question. One can argue about whether I should have used omega and omega^2 in the arXiv note, but again I prefer the choice I made.

Comment: $\omega$ is a common symbol for a lot of things, and the title doesn't tell us what it symbolizes here, and the body of the question doesn't tell us either.

Comment: We disagree slightly, but there's no point in arguing. An early paragraph in the body of the question says exactly what the question is, and consequently what the symbol in the title stands for. And the tag names being elliptic curves and diophantine equations, the reader of the title has a general idea of what they're in for, and can click on it or pass it by. Anyway I hope you enjoy the note, and can help with the question. All my best.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/455475/for-which-primes-p-in-mathbb-z-is-p-omega-the-sum-of-two-cubes-in-mathb#comment1179437_455475), sorry, since my username doesn't have a `.` I didn't receive the `@` notification.  The link seems to work for me.  What happens when you try to follow it?

Comment: @L Spice   There was a further edit by C7X of the question--now the link works for me, and, I hope, for other viewers. Thanks.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/455475/for-which-primes-p-in-mathbb-z-is-p-omega-the-sum-of-two-cubes-in-mathb#comment1181009_455475), the [further edit](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/455475/3) didn't change the link, and it seems to me to work when clicked directly from [my revision](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/455475/2).  But, anyway, as long as all is well, then it doesn't really matter when it was fixed.